# Почему не удаляется конкретный объект по id из массива в LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript

По нажатию на кнопку `js--btn-delete` должен удалятся конкретный объект по id из массива в LocalStorage.

```js
function UserTable({ form, content, userInfo, addButton }) {
    this.init = () => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.addUser(
                form.elements.name.value,
                form.elements.phone.value,
                form.elements.age.value,
                );
        });
        addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            form.reset();
            form.classList.add('open');
        });
        this.deleteUser()
        this.loadUsers();
    }

    //Данный метод удаляет данные конкретного пользоаптеля
    this.deleteUser = () => {
        document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('js--btn-delete')) {
                const userID = event.target.closest('tr').dataset.id;
                console.log('userID:',  userID)
                const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
                console.log('userData:', userData);
                userData.splice(0, userData.length, ...userData.filter(item => userID !== item.id));
                console.log('userData---Update:', userData);
                localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(userData));
            }
        })

    }
    //Данный метод создает данные нового пользователя
    this.addUser = (name, phone, age) => {
        const user = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            name,
            phone,
            age,
        }
        this.userTemplate(user);
        form.reset();
        form.classList.remove('open');
        const currentUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];
        currentUsers.push(user);
        localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(currentUsers));

    }
    //Данный метод при перезагрузке страницы подшружает данные из LocalStorage на сайт в таблицу
    this.loadUsers = () => {
        const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
        if (users) {
            users.forEach(user => this.userTemplate(user));
        }
    }
    //Создаем шаблон пользователя
    this.userTemplate = (user) => {
        content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',(
            `<tr data-id="${user.id}">`+
                `<td class="userId">${user.id}</td>`+
                `<td>${user.name}</td>`+
                `<td>${user.phone}</td>`+
                `<td>${user.age}</td>`+
                `<td>`+
                    `<button class="btn">View</button>`+
                    `<button class="btn">Edit</button>`+
                    `<button class="btn js--btn-delete">Delete</button>`+
                `</td>`+
            `</tr>`

        ))
    }
}
(new UserTable({
    form: document.querySelector('.js--form'),
    content: document.querySelector('.js--content'),
    userInfo: document.querySelector('.js--user'),
    addButton: document.querySelector('.js--add'),
})).init()
```

```css
table {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th,
table td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.card {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto auto 20px;
}
.card--user {
    display: none !important;
}
.card--user.open {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="js--content"></tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="card p-4">
        <button class="js--add btn btn-add btn-primary">Add user</button>
    </div>
    <form class="js--form card card--user p-4">
        <input type="hidden" name="id">

        <input class="form-control mb-1" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>

        <input class="form-control mb-1" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>

        <input class="form-control mb-3" type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" min="18" required>

        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 w-100" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
    <code class="card p-4">
        <pre class="js--user user-info">
            { asd: 'asd' }
        </pre>
    </code>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Преобразуйте userID в число. 2. Уберите splice, достаточно сделать вот так: `localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(userData.filter(item => userID !== item.id)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сравниваете строку с числом.

**Любой *прямой* доступ к атрибуту HTML из JavaScript вернёт строку.**

JS не понимает такое сравнение.

Для того, чтобы всё корректно работало, есть несколько вариантов:

##### Вариант 1. Присвоить переменной userID изначально число.

В 23 строке скрипта заменить:

```
const userID = event.target.closest('tr').dataset.id;
```

на:

```
const userID = Number(event.target.closest('tr').dataset.id);
```

Обратите внимание, что мы *обернули* строковое значение в число.
Это делает встроенный конструктор Number() в JavaScript.

##### Вариант 2. Сделать мягкое сравнение (заменить "!==" на "!=" без кавычек).

В 27 строке скрипта заменить:

```
userData.splice(0, userData.length, ...userData.filter(item => item.id !== userID));
```

на:

```
userData.splice(0, userData.length, ...userData.filter(item => item.id != userID));
```

Обратите внимание, что изменился оператор сравнения с жёсткого (!==) на мягкий (!=).

Подробнее про операторы сравнения можно узнать тут:
https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison

Comment: Просто так поставили дизлайк и всё.
Я новый участник. Хотелось бы узнать причину дизлайка. Что не так в моём ответе? Пожалуйста, объясните причину дизлайка.

Comment: Не знаю, кто поставил минус, однако второй вариант идеологически не правильный. Не стоит рекомендовать не строгое сравнение. + так же вся операция со splice выглядит коряво.

Comment: @Peter Kolosov спасибо за ответ, воспользовался вашим первым вариантом

Comment: @SwaD так splice же сам автор указал.

Comment: @NANO_996 Всегда пожалуйста)